# How to get mean of certain columns from different dataframes?

Tags: r, function

**Problem**

I want to use a function to get the mean numbers from different dataframes.

**Example dataframes**

```
WEEK.1 <- 1:52
DIF.4 <- runif(52, 0, 20)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(WEEK.1, DIF.4))

WEEK.2 <- 1:52
DIF.5 <- runif(52, 0, 20)
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(WEEK.2, DIF.5))

WEEK.3 <- 1:52
DIF.6 <- runif(52, 0, 20)
df3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(WEEK.3, DIF.6))
```

**Attempt**

a) Without a function, I'd have to repeat the following three times:

```
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(df), "\\.\\d", "")
df_ <- filter(df, WEEK >= 26)
mean(df_$DIF)
```

b) My attempt to do so with a function:

```
meanChange <- function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- str_replace_all(colnames(x), "\\.\\d", "")
  x_ <- filter(x, WEEK >= 26)
  mean(x_$DIF) 
}

x <- c("df", "df2", "df3")
changes <- as.data.frame(lapply(x, meanChange))
```

**Result**

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = character(0)) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
Called from: `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = character(0))
Browse[1]> Q
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are passing `y` as an argument to the function but using `x` inside.
- For the last line I think you mean `mean(x_$DIF)`

```
library(tidyverse)

meanChange <- function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- str_replace_all(colnames(x), "\\.\\d", "")
  x_ <- filter(x, WEEK >= 26)
  mean(x_$DIF) 
}
```

- Put the dataframes in a list and use `sapply` to apply the function.

```
y <- list(df, df2, df3)
sapply(y, meanChange)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possibile solution:

```r
# create a list of your dataframes
dfl <- list(df, df2, df3)

# apply mean function 
lapply(1:3, function(i) mean(dfl[[i]][[2]][which(dfl[[i]][[1]] >= 26)]))
```

Index `i` selects the single dataframe into list `dfl`. `[[1]]` and `[[2]]` select respectively column 1 and column 2 of each dataframe.

---

Another possible solution is:

```r
lapply(dfl, function(x) mean(x[[2]][which(x[[1]] >= 26)]))
```

Here `lapply` works directly with `dfl` without index.

---

**NOTE**: both solutions return a list as a result. If you want a vector use `sapply` rather than `lapply`